# Different domain for different language

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

I have developed a **multilingual** website using CodeIgniter's Language library.
How can i set **www.example.dk** for danish and **www.example.en** for english language.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest for you would be to make sub-domains on your server, it is quite easy, the way of doing it depends on what server service you are using, apache servers do it different than for example FreeNAS. Just search for how to create sub-domains for your server os.

Subdomains would look like this:

> www.dk.example.com

It can also be used for mobile versions of the site.

Hope this helps